# R - Distribute items equally among people by 3 different variables

Tags: r, loops, foreach

I have a dataframe which contains 3500 items with their values and categorised in 4 different types.

Then I have to distribute the items among 101 people who live in 28 different areas.

df1:

```
# A tibble: 3,500 × 4
    item    area   type  value
    <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
  1 Item1   Area2  C      481.
  2 Item2   Area26 C      409.
  3 Item3   Area17 B     1068 
  4 Item4   Area8  B      755.
  5 Item5   Area14 C      648.
  6 Item6   Area17 C      452.
  7 Item7   Area26 C      390.
  8 Item8   Area11 B      586.
  9 Item9   Area25 C      290.
 10 Item10  Area6  C      560.
 11 Item11  Area8  C      402.
 12 Item12  Area8  C      331.
 13 Item13  Area1  C      474.
 14 Item14  Area19 C      540.
 15 Item15  Area5  C      500 
 16 Item16  Area8  C      672 
 17 Item17  Area19 C      595 
 18 Item18  Area5  B      986.
 19 Item19  Area19 C      528.
 20 Item20  Area5  C      495.
 21 Item21  Area10 B     1171 
 22 Item22  Area26 B      872.
 23 Item23  Area7  C      556.
 24 Item24  Area19 C      564.
 25 Item25  Area26 C      513.
 26 Item26  Area2  C      889.
 27 Item27  Area24 C      467.
 28 Item28  Area19 C      442.
 29 Item29  Area24 B      841 
 30 Item30  Area19 C      435.
 31 Item31  Area5  C      527.
 32 Item32  Area17 C      300.
 33 Item33  Area15 C      407.
 34 Item34  Area5  C      659.
 35 Item35  Area19 B      350 
 36 Item36  Area19 C      478.
 37 Item37  Area10 C      923.
 38 Item38  Area22 C      860.
 39 Item39  Area18 C      605.
 40 Item40  Area8  C      360.
 41 Item41  Area5  C      487.
 42 Item42  Area1  B      939 
 43 Item43  Area5  C      642.
 44 Item44  Area5  C      576.
 45 Item45  Area12 C      560.
 46 Item46  Area8  C      402.
 47 Item47  Area11 C      540.
 48 Item48  Area5  C      494.
 49 Item49  Area5  C      472.
 50 Item50  Area22 C      455 
...

3496 Item3496 Area5  C      2526.
3497 Item3497 Area17 B       322.
3498 Item3498 Area5  C       201.
3499 Item3499 Area17 B       363.
3500 Item3500 Area19 C       231.
```

And another dataframe which contains people who live in each area.

df2:

```
# A tibble: 101 × 2
    area   name        
    <chr>  <chr>       
  1 Area1  William     
  2 Area1  Rhiannon    
  3 Area2  Reana       
  4 Area2  Milahd      
  5 Area2  Audrey      
  6 Area2  Geoffrey    
  7 Area2  Joan        
  8 Area2  Shaqeeqa    
  9 Area2  Maisoon     
 10 Area3  Kelvin      
 11 Area3  Ashley      
 12 Area4  Marco       
 13 Area4  Thuvan      
 14 Area5  Nathaniel   
 15 Area5  Demetrius   
 16 Area5  Jordan      
 17 Area5  Sadoon      
 18 Area5  Saje        
 19 Area5  Blakeslee   
 20 Area5  Briana      
 21 Area5  Aeneva      
 22 Area5  Pa          
 23 Area5  Benjamin    
 24 Area5  Abdul Waahid
 25 Area5  Atanasio    
 26 Area5  Ubaida      
 27 Area5  Jalen       
 28 Area5  Jarred      
 29 Area6  Kelsie      
 30 Area6  Alexander   
 31 Area6  Steven      
 32 Area7  Marco       
 33 Area7  Kelsey      
 34 Area8  Lynn        
 35 Area8  Nasreen     
 36 Area9  Kelsie      
 37 Area9  Jalonie     
 38 Area10 Hailey      
 39 Area10 Alexander   
 40 Area10 Steven      
 41 Area11 Kelvin      
 42 Area11 Jocelin     
 43 Area11 Ashley      
 44 Area11 Briana      
 45 Area12 Sarah       
 46 Area12 Cu Chulainn 
 47 Area12 Firdaus     
 48 Area13 Alisha      
 49 Area13 Ethan       
 50 Area14 Ella
...

 96 Area26 Muneeb      
 97 Area26 Luis        
 98 Area27 Marco       
 99 Area27 Kelsey      
100 Area28 Kaxee       
101 Area28 Mckylaa
```

Here there are df1 and df2 complete dataframes: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O_Gyp39sT-sIWZjOd4z85tcpBdJIaFDX/view?usp=sharing

My goal is to distribute all items in their corresponding areas, among all people of the area, in the same number of the different types available for each person (or as close as possible).

My first attempt to distribute them in Area1 was this:

```
# get all the items of Area1 of TYPE A and ordered by value
y <- df1 %>% filter(area=="Area1" & type=="A") %>%
  arrange(desc(value))

# List of people in Area1
v<-df2 %>% filter(area=="Area1")
v<-unique(v$name)

# Distribute them across all people 1 by 1
y$name<- rep(v, length.out = nrow(y))


# getting all items of Area1 of TYPE B and ordered by value
z <- df1 %>% filter(area=="Area1" & type=="B") %>%
  arrange(desc(value))

# Distribute them accross all people 1 by 1
z$name<- rep(v, length.out = nrow(z))

# Combining them
Area1<- rbind(y,z)
```

I'm looking to automate this process with a loop or a function in order to do the same with all 28 areas and all items types in each area.

I don't find the way and it's blowing my mind. So, any help would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that leverages `data.table`. After making sure that `df2` is unique, I do a cartesian join on `area`. I sort the values by `type` and `value`, and then use a helper function `f()` to identify the person to whom each item should be assigned:

```
library(data.table)

f <- function(x,l) {
  v = as.vector(sapply(seq_along(x), \(i) c(x[i:length(x)],x[0:(i-1)])))
  rep(v,length.out=l)
}

setDT(df1)[unique(setDT(df2)), on=.(area), allow.cartesian=T] %>% 
  .[order(type,-value)] %>% 
  .[,nid:=f(1:uniqueN(name),.N), .(area)] %>% 
  .[nid==1]
```

Note: change `names` to `name`, when using the updated data contained in `Rdata`.

Output: 3500 rows, with items within area equally distributed over names and types. For example, in Area1:

```
       name type  N
1:  William    A  1
2: Rhiannon    A  1
3:  William    B 12
4: Rhiannon    B 11
5: Rhiannon    C 27
6:  William    C 26
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @langtang. However, I get duplicate items in the final dataset. Maybe it's my fault because the sample data didn't reproduce correctly the complete data. May I send you the complete data? Or dou you know how can I post it here?

Comment: I reformulated the question and I uploaded the complete dataframes. Hope that helps! Thanks!

Comment: it seems to work on your .Rdata also. The result has 3500 rows. not sure what you mean by duplicates. notice that your original post used `names`` as a column in `df2`, but your actual `.Rdata` object has a column `name` in `df2`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
items <- paste0("Item",1:3000)
types <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
values <- runif(3000, min=0.1, max=10)
areas <- paste0("Area",1:27)

df1 <- data.frame (items)
df1$type <- types
df1$area <- rep(areas, length.out = nrow(df1))
df1$value <- values

names <- randomNames::randomNames(127, which.names = "first")
areas <- paste0("Area",1:27)

df2 <- data.frame (names)
df2$area <- rep(areas, length.out = nrow(df2))


f <- function(area, type){
y <- df1 %>% filter(area==area & type==type) %>%
  arrange(desc(value))

# List of people in Area1
v<-df2 %>% filter(area==area)
v<-unique(v$name)

# Distribute them across all people 1 by 1
y$name<- rep(v, length.out = nrow(y))
y
}

area_type <- df1 %>% select(area, type)  %>% distinct()
out <- map2(area_type$area, area_type$type, f)
out <- do.call(rbind, out)
head(out)
#>      items type   area    value   name
#> 1 Item1995    C Area24 9.998251 Joshua
#> 2 Item1991    C Area20 9.985092 Meghan
#> 3 Item2669    A Area23 9.983082 Valden
#> 4 Item2131    C Area25 9.979196 Ashley
#> 5  Item818    B  Area8 9.978811   Clay
#> 6  Item639    C Area18 9.975706 Hector
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In the code above, I wrapped one area-type iteration of your code in a function.  Then, I found the distinct area-type combinations in the data and used `map2()` from the `purrr` package to run the function using each observed combination of `area` and `type`.  Finally, put all the results in one data frame with `rbind()`.

---

### Edit: Answer to updated question

Here's an answer to the updated question with the real data.  This seems as though it might be more what you're looking for.

```r
load("~/Downloads/stackoverflow_dataframes.RData")
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(area) %>% 
  mutate(obs= 1:n())

tmp2 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(area) %>% 
  tally()

tmp1 <- df1 %>%
  arrange(area, type) %>%
  left_join(tmp2) %>% 
  group_split(area, type) %>% 
  map(., function(x){x$obs <- rep(1:x$n[1], max(1, ceiling(nrow(x)/x$n[1])), replace=FALSE)[1:nrow(x)]; x}) %>%
  bind_rows() %>% 
  left_join(df2)
#> Joining, by = "area"
#> Joining, by = c("area", "obs")
head(tmp1)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#>   item     area  type  value     n   obs name    
#>   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>   
#> 1 Item1064 Area1 A     5066.     2     1 William 
#> 2 Item3014 Area1 A     3434.     2     2 Rhiannon
#> 3 Item42   Area1 B      939      2     1 William 
#> 4 Item174  Area1 B      840      2     2 Rhiannon
#> 5 Item191  Area1 B     1189.     2     1 William 
#> 6 Item787  Area1 B      748.     2     2 Rhiannon


tmp1 %>% 
  group_by(area, type, obs) %>% 
  tally()
#> # A tibble: 234 × 4
#> # Groups:   area, type [74]
#>    area   type    obs     n
#>    <chr>  <chr> <int> <int>
#>  1 Area1  A         1     1
#>  2 Area1  A         2     1
#>  3 Area1  B         1    12
#>  4 Area1  B         2    11
#>  5 Area1  C         1    27
#>  6 Area1  C         2    26
#>  7 Area10 A         1     3
#>  8 Area10 A         2     2
#>  9 Area10 A         3     2
#> 10 Area10 B         1     7
#> # … with 224 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi @DaveArmstrong! It seems to work, but with your code we have a final dataset with 324000 rows because the items are duplicated. Maybe my explanation wasn't clear enough, but the items should be distributed only in their corresponding area. So, the final dataset should have 3000 rows (1 per item) distributed in its area, among the people who live in the same area, and each person should have the same (or as close as possible) number of items of each type.

Comment: I reformulated the question and I uploaded complete df1 and df2. I hope that helps! Thanks in advanced!

Comment: @kikusanchez I posted an updated answer after my original answer above.